# Uploading a large file to AWS database

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, file, upload, filestream

I have to upload large files to the AWS S3 bucket, approximately 500,000 lines long and 30MB. What would be the best way to do this, taking speed and number of calls into account?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload large objects using the AWS SDK. For example, assume you are using Java. To upload large files to Amazon S3 bucket, use [createMultipartUpload(](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html#completeMultipartUpload-software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.CompleteMultipartUploadRequest-)).

To see an example of how to use this method, see:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/S3ObjectOperations.java

Answer (score 0):

You can try uploading these files to s3 either from console or programmatically if you face any speed related issue and upload takes long time then you should consider using S3 multipart upload which upload files in multiple parts. There are several factors to consider when you use multipart. go through them before using it

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html

From my point of view uploading 30 MB file will be any issue. you can try directly.